# can i allow user to zoom in and out in GPUImage Framewor

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, opengl-es

i download gpuiimage framework from github and began use it in ios development

can i allow user to zoom in and out in GPUImage Framework in ios ? also i want to turn on and off the flash light in gpuimage framework ?

Comment: You're asking two questions here, and the first is undecipherable. In regards to the flash, read the comments here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/84 or look at the commented-out portions of the sample photo application that ships with the framework.

Answer (score 3):

The `GPUImage` framework is used for image manipulation. If you want the user to be able to zoom the photo, you'll want to look into adding a [UIPinchGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to the top level `UIImageView`. Then to use the devices LED you use the [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) framework. Having the GPUImage framework in your project will not inhibit you from doing any of this.